# Error Caused by The \makebox Command When Used Inside an Exam Document Header

Tags: errors, header-footer, exam, compilation-error

I am using the [exam](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Epsh/exam/examdoc.pdf) package for the first time. I wanted to edit the header as mentioned on page 117 of the documentation. The `\makebox` command is causing an error of the type: *Missing* `\begin{document}...` This happens when the optional arguments of size and position are used, i.e., `\makebox[size][position]{text}`, but when used without them, it raises no errors, however, the `text` in `\makebox{text}` would be misplaced. Any suggestions?

Here is a minimum non-working example (taken from the documentation linked above):

```
\documentclass[addpoints, 12pt]{exam}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\lhead{\large\bfseries Foundations of Mathematics (MATH113)\\ Midterm Exam, December 21, 2021}
\chead{}
% This is the line causing the problem!
% specifically: the optional arguments of \makebox[][]{}
\rhead[\large\bfseries Name:\enspace\makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}]{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot[]{Page \thepage}
\rfoot{}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \fbox{\fbox{\centering Minimum Working Example}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: are you inside the optional argument of another command if so you need to hide the inner `[]` so `{\makebox[size][position]{stuff}}`  with extra braces around teh outside

Comment: Thank you, David. This solves the problem. However, I guess the author of the 'exam' documentation should be notified about this issue in \makebox. A code in a documentation ought to work always.

Comment: you have not shown any code so it is impossible to say anything really The issue is completely unrelated to `\makebox` it is a general feature of latex optional atguments that if you have `\foo[ ... \zzz[t] ..]`  then the argument to `\foo` ends at the first `]` so is `\foo[ ... \zzz[]` and gives errors, you need  `\foo[{ ... \zzz[t] ..}]` so my guess is that it is your error in your document, not an issue with the exam package. But without seeing any example, hard to say.

Comment: oh sorry!! I just looked at the pdf you linked to, yes that is a documentation error in the package you should report it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was provided by David Carlisle in the comments section. It involves wrapping the `\makebox[size][position]{text}` command by extra curly brackets to *hide* the optional arguments of size and position so that the `\makebox` command won't raise the error it does as shown in the question.

```
\documentclass[addpoints, 12pt]{exam}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\lhead{\large\bfseries Foundations of Mathematics (MATH113)\\ Midterm Exam, December 21, 2021}
\chead{}
\rhead[\large\bfseries Name:\enspace{\makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}}]{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot[]{Page \thepage}
\rfoot{}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \fbox{\fbox{\centering Minimum Working Example}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Exam document header after fixing \makebox]